# is it better to use intent to add xml layouts than using addview()?

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

Im new to android development and I am using addView() and removeViewAt() for switching between my xml layouts.

I saw my friend using Intents to do this and saw that each of his xml layout has its own activity class that calls setContentView() to display the views.

So I am wondering of which method would be better to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just removing all the views and placing new views in the same Activity(Activity in simple word is single screen in which user interacts). But this is the wrong way of doing.
(Because you can not take use of Activity life cycles).

The same thing you can do by creating activities for all screen (For switching between the activities we use Intent). Every Activity has its own life cycle. so you can achieve lot of things.
Since You are in android so I will suggest you to go through these Links -

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are using a single activity, and dynamically changing the layout displayed via java code. your friend, uses multiple activities and "jumps" from one to another using Intents.

I think using intents to change activities is the most correct way to do so. If you are using plain activities (I mean, you don't use fragments), you might want to create different activities for each screen of your app.
If you plan to use fragments, the normal procedure is to create an activity that contains the fragments, and dynamically change the fragments.

I'm not sure if there are any security or performance implications in doing it the way you do, but the "official" way, the one you see in every book and tutorial, is the one with different activities and intents.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In Android you usually seperate your application to activities. Each activity does something.
For example in the gmail application the (usually) first activity shows you the incoming emails. From the navigation drawer (The menu in the left) you can jump to other activities. If you press on the "New Mail" button in the action bar it opens a new activity to write an email.

This is how android applications should work. Each activity does something and has its own life. When you press on the back button you go back to the previous activity if nothing else was specified.

When android is out of resources he is killing the active activities, while saving their state. That means that he takes them off the memory but saves their state so it can start them again later. It has a list of the most not used activities and kills them first. When the user navigates back to that activity, android uses the existing instance and if it was killed he makes a new one using the saved state.

Another reason to use activities is that they can be called when certain events occur. Your main activity is probably started by an intent with an action MAIN. You can see it in the android manifest file. There are other actions like SEND. When another app wants to share data with other apps (For example if the user presses on the share button) it sends an intent with the SEND action and the user can choose from all the activities that deal with that action (you can add it to the android manifest).

There is a lot of information about activities in android developers. here's the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html